# Ruby Interpolation

Tags: ruby, string

Could someone explain why doing this:

```
%{#$"}
```

in irb produces the following?

```
=> "[\"enumerator.so\", \"enc/encdb.so\", \"enc/big5.so\", \"enc/cp949.so\", \"enc/emacs_mule.so\", \"enc/euc_jp.so\", \"enc/euc_kr.so\", \"enc/euc_tw.so\", \"enc/gb2312.so\", \"enc/gb18030.so\", \"enc/gbk.so\", \"enc/iso_8859_1.so\" ... ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the " maybe asking it return all environment variables surrounding the ruby installation (vague guess)

Comment: `$LOADED_FEATURES == $"` - see [ruby/doc/globals.rdoc](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/globals.rdoc)

Comment: Ew, there's a Perl in my Ruby.

Comment: The `IRB` tag is irrelevant and potentially misleading (it's not an IRB issue), so I suggest you remove it.

Comment: This illustrates why special variables can be dangerous. The string in question also illustrates why Perl, and code written in a terse, overly compact style, results in difficult to understand and maintain code. It's taking advantage of some special, esoteric, features of Ruby, that most of us leave alone to live their lives in dark corners of the language.

Comment: I've never known Ruby has that variable, until now :D Anyway, very interesting to know.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`%{ ... }` is a string literal. It's similar to `"..."`.

```
%{a string} == "a string"
# => true
```

`#{expr}` inside those string literal is interpolation. An expression `expr` inside the substituted with the value of it. For global variable you can omit `{` and `}`.

```
"#{1 + 2}"
# => "3"
```

```
%{#$"} == $".to_s
# => true
```

`$"` is [one of pre-defined variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/globals_rdoc.html): an array of loaded module names.